# Possible to access PHP parse_str array values by index?

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, function, query-string

Hopefully this is a simple answer or doable in some other way.  I want to use parse_str to store my querystring values in an array.

```
$querystring = "value1=SKIP&value2=SKIP&value3=GET&value4=GET";
parse_str($querystring, $fields);
```

Accessing the data by name works correctly:

```
echo $fields['value3'];
```

... but accessing via index **does not**:

> echo $fields[2];

The reason I want to access by index instead of name is because after the 2nd array value, the rest of the querystring parameters will be DYNAMICALLY generated.  In other words, for the processing I'm doing -- I want to get all parameters AFTER the 2nd one.  To do that, I was going to use a simple FOR loop starting from the 3rd value in the array to the **sizeof(myArray)**;.

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to generate an indexed array then. You could for example use:

```
$indexed = array_values($fields);
print $indexed[2];  // eqivalent to $fields["value3"];
```

Note that the index starts from 0.

If you want you could also combine the named array with the indexed version:

```
$fields = array_merge($fields, array_values($fields));
$fields[2] == $fields["value3"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate a string with an integer:

`echo $fields["value" . $myInteger + 1];`

where `myInteger` is your value (for loop, etc.). You need to add 1 because your strings are one-based.

Example:

```
for ($i = 2; $i < sizeof($myArray); $i++)
{
    echo $fields["value" . $i + 1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
    $fields[$i] = $value; //or just put your code here, and use $i
    $i++;
}

for ($j = 2; $j < $i; $j++) {
    //do something with $fields[$j]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
$querystring = "value1=SKIP&value2=SKIP&value3=GET&value4=GET";
parse_str($querystring, $fields);
$arr = array_slice($fields, 2, count($fields), true);

foreach($arr as $key=>$value) {
        echo $key . "=>" . $value;
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.